# Compatibility of Grignard reagents with aromatic nitro groups

Tags: organic-chemistry, nitro-compounds, grignard-reagent

Is it possible to form a Grignard reagent from 1-chloro-3-nitrobenzene, as shown below?

[image]

Specifically, will the nitro group react with the Grignard reagent formed?

Comment: No. Aromatic nitro groups react with grignards - see Bartoli reaction.

Comment: An organozinc would probably work

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to accomplish with your organometallic reagent.

Answer (score 5):

Aromatic nitro groups are not compatible with Grignards as they react with the nitro group. An example of this being useful is the Bartoli synthesis of indoles from vinyl Grignards (Tet. Letts. 1989, **30** 2129, Curr. Org. Chem.. 2005, **9**, 163). The first step of the Bartoli is addition of the vinyl Grignard to the O of the N=O of the nitro group so I presume this would be true for other Grignards and is the reason for the incompatibility.